# How to share project to Git repo in Eclipse without the folder with the same name as the project?

Tags: git, eclipse, github, egit

In general, the name of a Git repo is the same as the name of project, there will no longer be a folder with the same name inside the repo. This structure is like [commons-io](https://github.com/apache/commons-io).

But when I

1. create a repo "com.abc.test" in GitHub and create a Java project "com.abc.test" in local
2. clone the repo from GitHub
3. share this Java project to repo

The structure looks like this

[image]

It's not what I want. What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a repo "com.abc.test" in GitHub
2. Clone the repo from GitHub
3. Create a Java project "com.abc.test" in local, but do not use the default location. Instead, use the clone's location. Some options will apparently be locked out, but nothing you can't adjust afterward.

[image: New Java Project wizard, first page with "Use default location" unchecked]

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks. But what should I do if I've already created a project in workspace ？

Comment: Delete the project from the workspace without deleting the underlying resources, physically move the contents, then import the project from the Git Repositories View--except if it's a Maven project, in which case use their import wizard.